# Amp-font always re-render text

Tags: amp-html

Any body work on AMP-font?

As the example below here. Amp font is a good practice to solve the problem "text display as soon as possible" but one thing I considering is the text always re-rendered.

https://ampbyexample.com/playground/#url=https%3A%2F%2Fampbyexample.com%2Fcomponents%2Famp-font%2Fsource%2F&mode=iPhone+5%2FSE

By default, website applies font serif if the font was not loaded. After loading font. The font will be applied to the text. Even you set `timeout` =0 the text still be re-rendered.

Any suggestion please!

Thank guys.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43463046/edit) the question to be on-topic: include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that duplicates the problem. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you describe in more detail what the behavior you're looking for is? `amp-font` has a wide range of uses, so the answer will depend on what you want to achieve.